# create NewItem automatically in a seperate list from field in a different list in sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

sharepoint knowledge level: n00bish

I  have seen a few other posts on here that are similar, but it seems to be something different in each. so, sorry if this is a direct repeat, because I did do some looking around before posting.

Things to know:
I am using sharepoint foundation to do this(so if that is my first issue let me know, because I do have access to the enterprise version if I need to do it there)

So I am making a list to keep track of some hardware and in list1 I have

> List1
>
> > serial number    
> >     make/model       
> >     deployed to: |location1| |location2|

I currently have the `deployed to` as a lookup to another list on the site to where it gets it's information

What I am wanting to do:
When a location is selected in `deployed to` it creates a new item in List2 with the name of `location1` along with serial number and make/model (and any other field if i decide to add to the list)

*If I can get this worked out, ultimately I want to instead of `deployed to` pulling it's information from 1 list, I want it to be able to look at a certain lists to choose where the new item gets added(if that is possible)
example:

> List1
>
> > serial number
> >     make/model
> >     deployed to: | list3 | | list4 |

Which then will add the information to the list chosen

Any help would be very much appreciated!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need SharePoint designer to create workflows to copy your data to a new list.

I assume you want to break out the lists by location (each one has it's list)?  If you keep them all in the same list, you benefit by being able to create special views and filters, as well as exporting the entire list to Excel if you needed to report on it. It's much more difficult to bring all that data together from separate lists without an actual reporting tool to do it for you.

You won't be able to merge multiple data sources on your form out of the box.  You would have to do some customizations using either SharePoint Designer, JavaScript, or in Visual Studio.  You could however, still use multiple lists, just create one more "master" location list and use that as your reference. You can then build the workflow logic to copy to that list based on selection.

Comment: yes, i thought of the master list idea and just put the different locations into groups on a view(which i think would be the easier option right now)

if i were to go that route, i'm guessing i would still have to use SPdesigner or a workflow to put the data into a different list?

reporting isn't an issue because each piece of hardware has it's own master list, the location is simply collecting all those other list's info to display. the only reporting would be of each location if used.

if SPdesigner and workflows need to be used, you have any good resources i can check out?